# django-admin command not regonized

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have installed **django** on my computer but when i try to run any `django-admin` command on my terminal i get this error:

```
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or   
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ django-admin startproject app
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am using powershell and visual studio code 
Is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: What is the output when you enter `python -m django --version` in powershell?

Comment: 3.1.7 Is this an old version?

Comment: No, it's not. However, make sure you have installed it correctly going over [this how to install django on Windows guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/windows/).

Answer (score 0):

Django is a widely used framework, and it can be installed on multiple architectures and operating systems, now, understanding this premise, imagine that you are in front of the computer trying to answer the question you are asking.

For some collaborators it is really difficult or impossible to try to reproduce the error that is being presented to you without more details, my advice is to reformulate the question, for example:

1. I have an old computer running windows 10.
2. I installed the binary version for windows of python 3.7.
3. I installed pip, poetry, pipenv, and virtualenv to make a virtual environment.
4. I created the virtual environment with the following instruction .....
5. I installed django with the following statement ....
6. I am trying to create my project with this instruction ....
7. I get the following error message.

BTW, all the instructions I am executing from my PyCharm IDE .....

I recommend you read the following manual [http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

I hope this can be of help to you so that you can provide more information and in this way receive a correct answer.